# I want to understand this circuit and these equations

Tags: operational-amplifier, circuit-analysis, matrix, equation

I have a hard time understanding this circuit that I’ve been given because of the way it looks. I don’t know why, but electrical circuits seem very confusing to me even after reading the chapters to understand what is going on.

The books only provides simple circuits, but for my assignments I have to do more complicated circuits. Here is my circuit:

[image: OpAmp+BJT constant current source]

I have eight equations related to this circuit that I also don’t understand too much of.

$$ \begin{aligned} V1 &= \frac{R3}{R3+R4}\cdot VCC  \\
    V4 &= A_{OL}\cdot(V1-V5) \\
 V4-V3 &= I3\cdot R1         \\
 V3-V5 &= V_{BE}             \\
    I6 &= \beta\cdot I3      \\
    V5 &= I5\cdot R2         \\
    V6 &= VCC - V_{LED1}     \\
    I5 &= I3+I6  \end{aligned}$$

Here are the questions I have to answer:

> These circuit equations need to be solved in order to determine I6 - expressed in terms of R1, R2, R3, R4, AOL, VCC, β, VBE, and VLED1. Additionally, the solution needs to be simplified and interpreted for ideal component values.
>
> 1. Rewrite the 8 circuit equations so that the system of equations is ready to be written in matrix form: A̿∙x̿=b̿, where x̿ are the unknowns.
> 2. Write the coefficient matrix A̿ for the 8 unknowns (x̿), result matrix b̿, and the augmented matrix ((A:b))̿ for solving the system of equations.

I want to learn how to do it, so an explanation/hint in the right direction would mean so much. I want to learn how to solve this problem.

Comment: i also have the answer but that doesnt help me cause i dont know how to go from we went from A to B. The answer to the first equation 1 V_1+ 0V_3  + 0*V_4  + 0V_5  +0V_6  0*I_3  +0*I_5  + 0*I_6=R_3/(R_3+R_4 )*V_CC

Comment: If you consider the op-amp as a perfect element (\$A_{OL}\$ approaches infinity), then you know that both INV and NINV inputs are at the same potential. Therefore, the voltage across \$R_3\$ is the same as the voltage across \$R_2\$, imposing the emitter current. Emitter and collector currents are linked so here you go...

Comment: An electrical engineer with a little experience will quickly see this is an LED driven by a current source determined by V5/R2, where V5 is set by voltage divider R4. R3. Your exercise to set this up as a matrix involving every parameter in the entire circuit probably leads up to noting which of the numerous variables are pretty much irrelevant (given reasonable components), or at least less than the variability of LED brightness :-)
Ie: beta=infinity, R1=0, I6=I5, V5=V1; Hence I6=VCC*(R3/(R3+R4))/R2

Comment: You're missing an important relationship for V5.  Think about op amp rules.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're overthinking this.

One of the golden opamp rules says:

> An operational amplifier in negative feedback configuration will, in the static case, enforce that the voltage difference between its two inputs is 0.

In other words, it makes such output that it pulls your inverting input to the same potential as its non-inverting input, which is at V1. (If you don't know how to write a linear equation that defines V1 through R3, R4 and VCC, this circuit is half a year ahead of your current skillset, and you need to go back, maybe get a better beginner's book for you.)

So, V1 being an "input", we pull V5 to be == V1.

Because between the node labeled V5 and ground, there's only a resistor, R2, that means inherently that the voltage across that resistor has to be V5. And due to Ohm's law, that sets the current through the resistor, I5 = V1/R2.

So, this circuit is a controllable current source – I5 gets defined by the input, V1, and the size of R2.

Now, where does that current come from? There's only two things "feeding" into R5:

1. The current coming from VCC through the LED, I6.
2. The current coming from the opamp output, I3.

We can't *really* know how they are related to each other without making (quite a few) assumptions about what resistors and input voltages (V1, VCC) we're talking about, and in which operational region we operate the transistor. So, if your problem doesn't state it, we honestly can't answer it.

But assuming your problem *means* to state "the transistor is operated well in the linear regime", that means that the collector current I6 is a fixed multiple \$\beta\$ of the base current I3. Add them up to get I5,

\begin{align}
I5 &= I3 + I6 \\
&= 1/\beta \cdot I6 + I6\\
&= I6 \cdot (1+ 1/\beta)\\
I6 &= \frac{I5}{1+1/\beta}\\
&= \frac{V1}{R2\cdot(1+1/\beta)}
\end{align}

Now you have a linear (OK, *linearized*, because \$\beta\$ being a fixed constant is only true for a small region) equation relating the LED current to V1.

I guess from here you can construct the matrix for at least that part of 1.

Answer (score 0):

Lets rename all given constants to \$k_{1..7}\$ to make clear what is given and what you are looking for:

$$ \begin{aligned}
V_1 &= k_1                   &\text{ with } k_1 &:= \frac{R_3}{R_3 + R_4}\cdot V_{CC}\\ 
V_4 &= k_2 \cdot (V_1 - V_5) &\text{ with } k_2 &:= A_{OL}  \\
V_4 - V_3 &= k3 \cdot I_3    &\text{ with } k_3 &:= R_1\\  
V_3 - V_5 &= k4              &\text{ with } k_4 &:= V_{BE}\\  
I_6 &= k_5 \cdot I_3         &\text{ with } k_5 &:=\beta\\
V_5 &= I_5 \cdot k_6         &\text{ with } k_6 &:= R_2\\
V_6 &= k_7                   &\text{ with } k_7 &:= V_{CC} - V_{LED1}\\  
I_5 &= I_3 + I_6
\end{aligned}
$$

Now bring all unknowns to the left side of each equation and sort unknowns in columns which gives you already almost the matrix equation:

```
       V1      V3      V4      V5      I3      I6      V6      I5
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
       V1                                                         = k1
   -k2*V1          +   V4 + k2*V5                                 = 0
              -V3  +   V4 +        -k3*I3                         = 0
               V3  +          -V5                                 = k4
                                   -k5*I3  +   I6                 = 0
                               V5          +               -k6*I5 = 0
                                                       V6         = k7
                                      -I3  +  -I6           +  I5 = 0
```

For the matrix equation \$Ax=b\$
\$x = [V_1, V_3, V_4, V_5, I_3, I_6, V_6, I_5]\$ is the vector of the unknowns
\$b = [k_1, 0, 0, k_4, 0, 0, k_7, 0]\$ is the vector of the right sides of the equations and
\$A = 
\begin{bmatrix}
   1 &    0 & 0 &   0 &    0 &  0 & 0 &    0 \\
-k_2 &    0 & 1 & k_2 &    0 &  0 & 0 &    0 \\
   0 &   -1 & 1 &   0 & -k_3 &  0 & 0 &    0 \\
   0 &    1 & 0 &  -1 &    0 &  0 & 0 &    0 \\
   0 &    0 & 0 &   0 & -k_5 &  1 & 0 &    0 \\
   0 &    0 & 0 &   1 &    0 &  0 & 0 & -k_6 \\
   0 &    0 & 0 &   0 &    0 &  0 & 1 &    0 \\
   0 &    0 & 0 &   0 &   -1 & -1 & 0 &    1
\end{bmatrix}
\$
is the matrix of the coefficients of the left sides of the equations.